# Determine if two files belongs to the same volume

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am working in the some ntfs hardlinks projects.   I want to known how to determine if two files (with full path) belongs to the same volume.

Comment: GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint

Comment: Thanks. Post as answer, I upvote this, because I accept David answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options to find the volume information associated with a file:

1. Find the root path for the two files, and use [`GetVolumeInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993.aspx) to find the volume name.
2. Open a handle to the file and pass that to [`GetVolumeInformationByHandleW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964920.aspx).

Note that `GetVolumeInformationByHandleW` requires Vista, that is it is not available on XP.

Check for equality by comparing the volume serial number.

Comment: I think towards the serial number is better than volume name.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are right. I got it into my head that volume name was the information of interest.