# How to determine if two files share a physical device (as opposed to a logical device/filesystem)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cross-platform

I will be working on a C program that scans user-specified files and directory trees. To speed up the process, I would like to take advantage of parallel reads using threads, but reading two devices on the same physical device could greatly slow down both reads instead. I need to be able to tell if a pair of files are on the same *physical* device, *not the same logical device.* I also need this to happen without using external libraries or non-C code.

I know I can use `stat()` to find out if two files share a logical device, but if two files are located on e.g. `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5` and share `/dev/sda` I would like to be able to tell that they share a physical device even though `stat()` will say they're on different "devices." Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this cross-platform (Windows, Linux, macOS), and even more ideally, have it work with things like md or lvm volumes too. Unfortunately, the only way that I can come up with to do this is complicated; on Linux for example, I assume I'll need to build Linux-specific knowledge (parsing sysfs?) into the program since entirely different physical volumes can still share major device numbers.

I have found the answer [Determine if two files belongs to the same volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498968/determine-if-two-files-belongs-to-the-same-volume) and it is not a duplicate. That question uses `GetVolumeInformation` on Windows and that's helpful, but I don't know of an equivalent on Linux or macOS.

If this is not a practical thing to do, what alternatives could be used? Benchmarking file read performance and changing behavior if read speed drops?

Comment: On a Linux terminal you may use something like: "df  pathfilename".

Comment: You can find some information via the `stat()` or `fstat()` calls — the `st_dev` member of `struct stat` ([`<sys/stat.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)
) identifies which logical device the file is on. Identifying physical devices isn't possible in general; you could have a single disk divided into partitions, but (especially with distributed file systems, or with RAID systems), you can identify physical devices. You can rely on the o/s to do the best possible job with its cacheing, etc. With SSD, it isn't clear there's much of a problem anyway.

Comment: Hi, @JonathanLeffler. I'm interested in this question, and I'm indagating about stat/fstat. My question, now, is: what's the data kind I may use to printout the value of st_dev?

Comment: Writing st_dev as an int I note that is a 16 bit number that contains the major version in the high byte and the minor in the low byte. It this true?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Those calls do not identify physical devices, only logical ones. Two partitions of a drive are on the same physical device but show different device numbers in `*stat()` calls. I already covered `stat()` not doing this in the question.

Comment: @JodyLeeBruchon and @JonathanLeffler. But if we may identify the device name starting from the info `st_dev` we may understand which is the physical disk. /dev/sda{x} is a different disk from /dev/sdb{x}. Is this true?

Comment: Yes — and I said there isn't a trivial (or even non-trivial but reliable) way to identify physical devices,.  You need to measure to prove that it is actually a problem.  I don't think you're going to be able to demonstrate that it is a serious problem, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @SirJoBlack Yes, the device number is major/minor, but you can't use that as a reliable way to find shared physical drives. `sda` has 8,0 to 8,15 and `sdb` has 8,16 to 8,31, but `md0` is 9,0 while `md1` is 9,1 and they may or may not share one or more physical drives; same goes for dm devices. It looks like parsing sysfs may be the only good way to do it on Linux without bringing in external dependencies that speak `udev` or similar.